# How can I use a multi-line SELECT statement in HSQLDB to export data?

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb

When I run the following script in HSQLDB 2.2.5 using the command "java -jar sqltool.jar --rcFile sqltool.rc db_file q.sql", I get the error message: "user lacks privilege or object not found: SELECT". If I make the `\x` command a single-line statement, HSQLDB will execute the script successfully. I'd like to break my `\x` into multiple lines for better readability. How can I use a multi-line `\x` command in an HSQLDB script?

```
--q.sql
DROP TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" (
  "C1" VARCHAR(10),
  "C2" VARCHAR(10),
  "C3" VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" ("C1", "C2", "C3") VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" ("C1", "C2", "C3") VALUES ('d', 'e', 'f');

DROP TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" (
  "C1" VARCHAR(10),
  "C2" VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" ("C1", "C2") VALUES ('a', 'b');
INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" ("C1", "C2") VALUES ('u', 'v');

* *DSV_COL_DELIM=,
* *DSV_ROW_DELIM=\n
* *DSV_TARGET_FILE=results.csv

\x SELECT
( SELECT TOP 1 "T2"."C1" FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" "T2" WHERE "T2"."C1" = "T1"."C1") AS "T2C1",
"T1"."C2" AS "T1C2"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" "T1"
ORDER BY "T2C1", "T1C2"
```

**UPDATE:** Per @Blaine's suggestion, I switched to HSQLDB 2.2.6 and replaced the `\x` command in the above script with the following:

```
\.

SELECT
(SELECT TOP 1 "T2"."C1" FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" "T2"
 WHERE "T2"."C1" = "T1"."C1") AS "T2C1",
"T1"."C2" AS "T1C2"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" "T1"
ORDER BY "T2C1", "T1C2"

.;

\x :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires version 2.2.6.

Once you have 2.2.6, `\x?` will show you everything you need to know.

Since you want this to work from a script, you would use raw mode to enter your multi-line SQL statement into SqlTool's command buffer, then use `\x :`.  Mnemonic:  ":" indicates SqlTool's edit buffer.

Comment: I got the pre-release snapshot of 2.2.6 from http://www.hsqldb.org/support/hsqldb_16.zip and replaced "\x SELECT" by "\x : SELECT" in my script. But, I got the error message: "unexpected token: *". Do I need to make any other changes?

Comment: HyperSQL 2.2.6 is now public.  You can download the zip from Sourceforge.  See http://hsqldb.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/hsqldb/base/trunk/testrun/sqltool/dsv-multiline.sql for a working example that does just what you want.

Comment: I edited your answer to include the command that I successfully ran in HSQLDB 2.2.6.

Comment: Since my edit was rejected (See http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/144660), I edited my question.